# Identifying data segment in Win32/Win64

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, win64, data-segment

I am a DLL loaded in the memory space of some process. I am part of a number of DLLs that are present in this process, some loaded dynamically and some statically.

There is a "data gem" left for me to discover somewhere in this process's space and we will assume it is in a "data" segment (ie not in some weird self modifying code).

I need to find it. I need to search memory, eg do a memcmp() but I do not know where to start looking. Maybe I can brute force search from 0 to many-gigs but that will throw read-access or execute-only exceptions and maybe I will be able to handle these exceptions so that I do not bring the whole process down. But it sounds dodgy.

Is there a more intelligent way to search ? Off the top of my head, I could look into the data segments of the main process because there is a way to get the address ranges from the NT header somehow, and I do know the process which I have got loaded in. Then I could enumerate all loaded DLLs and look inside their spaces too.

Can anyone please suggest a method or even tell me if I am on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate all the loaded modules in you process via [`EnumProcessModules`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631(v=vs.85).aspx) using [`GetCurrentProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx) as the process handle. Then for each module you can call [`GetModuleInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683201(v=vs.85).aspx) which will return you a [`MODULEINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684229(v=vs.85).aspx) struct which tells you exactly where in memory the module is loaded and its size. Alternatively you can call [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx)
 and examine the module on disk.

Do note that reading arbitrary memory in a process - even the one you're currently running in - can have issues. For example if another thread is running at the same time as yours then it can affect the module table as you're iterating over it.

Comment: This does not tell you, where in the modules the .data segment is. This is necessary to not search through code looking for data.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing a Win32 process may use memory that it has acquired via a number of methods, I think it all ends up using VirtualAlloc and a bit higher level with HeapCreate et al. In the end the data gem may be in a module's "data" segments, or on a heap, even on a stack - both allocated with VirtualAlloc. There may well be other memory allocation methods.

When we look at a Windows process it will have a bunch of DLLs loaded many of which will be using their own "heap" and/or direct VirtualAlloc calls. Others will be sharing the main process's heap.

I have enumerated the process's heaps using GetProcessHeaps and then HeapWalk concentrating only on PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY_BUSY and I have, luckily, found what I was looking for. My "heapwalk" is by no means an exhaustive search.

I have not found a way, and it is academic for me now, to link a heap entry (block) to a particular module. Similarly if I were to look into all the VirtualAllocs I would not know how to trace the allocated blocks back to some code running inside a module. But that step is academic.